# Polymer Appengine Web page not rendering elements

Tags: python, google-app-engine, polymer, paper-elements

I have begun developing a template for web development using the PWA and Polymer tutorial here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up

I have gone through each step (1-4) and successfully deployed to appengine using python. When i serve the webpage on Localhost it renders all the polymerelements just fine, but once i deploy to appengine none of the elements get rendered.

Here are images of both.

Localhost: 
[image]

Deployed to appengine:
[image]

Now I have double checked all the steps and i do not see anything i have missed. Any reason why this would not show up with any of the styling and elements? Once it is in appengine do I have to serve it like on localhost? All help is very appreciated, thanks in advance!

Let me know if you need any of the code as well. ALl of the code is exactly replicated from the tutorial link above.

EDIT: here are the errors im getting in my browser console:
[image]

Most of the errors are this one: this._desugarBehaviors is not a function

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Yes, I just editted with the errors im receiving.